# preventDefault and stopPropagation will not allow to change css property of div

Tags: html, css, angularjs, touchscreen

I am working on touch screen and change from onclick on div to touchstart so that speed of click work fast. But problem is that using this way when i touch on div event working fast but css property to change background color is not working now. Here is my code:

```
<div class="numpad" id="numpad" align="center">
    <div style="display:flex;">
        <kbd touchpad="call(1)">1
            <div class="background">&nbsp;</div>
        </kbd>
        <kbd touchpad="call(2)">2
            <div class="background">ABC</div>
        </kbd>
        <kbd touchpad="call(3)">3
            <div class="background">DEF</div>
        </kbd>
    </div>
```

angular directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('numpad', function($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'html/directives/numpadOpenr.html',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

            scope.number = ngModel;

            scope.call = function(number) {
                var value = scope.number.$viewValue || '';
                scope.number.$setViewValue(value + number);
            };

            scope.remove = function() {
                var value = scope.number.$viewValue || '';
                if (value.length > 0) {
                    scope.number.$setViewValue(value.substring(0, value.length - 1));
                }
            };

        }
    };
});

angular.module('myApp').directive("touchpad", [function () {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind("touchstart click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            scope.$apply(attrs["touchpad"]);
        });
    }
}]);
```

css:

```
 kbd, .key {
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 2.2em;
        font: normal .85em "Lucida Grande", Lucida, Arial, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -ms-border-radius: 3px;
        -o-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #555;
    }

    kbd[title], .key[title] {
        cursor: help;
    }

    kbd {
        border: 1px solid #c4c6ca;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        background-color: transparent;
        flex:1;
        height: 2.2em;
    }

    kbd:active {
        background: #e6e7e8;
    }

    .numpad kbd {
        margin: 3px;
        font-size: xx-large;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    kbd div.background {
        font-size:x-small;
    }

    .numpad kbd:hover, .numpad kbd:active, .numpad kbd:focus {
        background-color: #dceef7;
    }
```

Can someone tell me is there any way that css numpad kbd:active, numpad kbd:focus start work using same strategy where i am using  e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution its little bit ugly but working. If add a timeout function which help to disable entry into onclick function call then it will work. Her is a code.

```
 var doubleClickCheck = true;

            scope.call = function(number) {
                if (doubleClickCheck) {
                    var value = scope.number.$viewValue || '';
                    scope.number.$setViewValue(value + number);
                    reset();
                } 
            };

            scope.remove = function() {
                if (doubleClickCheck) {
                    var value = scope.number.$viewValue || '';
                    if (value.length > 0) {
                        scope.number.$setViewValue(value.substring(0, value.length - 1));
                    }
                    reset();
                }
            };

            function reset() {
                doubleClickCheck = false;
                $timeout(function () {
                    doubleClickCheck = true;
                }, 150)
            }
```